# How to convert "0:2017-12-31T19:00:00.000Z 1:2018-01-09T19:00:00.000Z " to array?

Tags: javascript

I have following csv row:

`{
  "name": "Alliant Energy - Iowa",
  "metering_type": "Annual Net",
  "metering_dates": "\"0:2017-12-31T19:00:00.000Z 1:2018-01-09T19:00:00.000Z \"",
  "meter_values": "\"0:'NY' 1:'LG' 2:'BG Los'\""
}`

Where i want to convert `metering_dates` and `meter_values` to an array.

We can see that each new array item have index number:
`0:value 1:value ... n:value`

Update:
That actually come from csv file, not only dates can be array items.
eg
`0:'blah blah' 1:'blah blah'`

Update 2:
I need somehow to know if string is array or just string:

`0:'blah blah' 1:'blah blah'` --> array

`'blah blah'` --> not array

Comment: What blah blah can hold ?

Comment: @CodeManiac added real word example, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let str = "0:2017-12-31T19:00:00.000Z 1:2018-01-09T19:00:00.000Z"

let op = str.split(' ').map(e=> e.replace(/^\d+:/,''))

console.log(op)
```

You can test for pattern `\d+:` to check if it's in array format or not

```js
let obj = {
  "name": "Alliant Energy - Iowa",
  "metering_type": "Annual Net",
  "metering_dates": "\"0:2017-12-31T19:00:00.000Z 1:2018-01-09T19:00:00.000Z \"",
  "meter_values": "\"0:'NY' 1:'LG' 2:'BG Los'\"",
  'test': 'some value some value'
}

let {meter_values:value, metering_dates:date,test} = obj
let testFunc = (value) => /^(?:")?\d+:/.test(value) ? 'Array' : 'String'
console.log(testFunc(value))
console.log(testFunc(date))
console.log(testFunc(test))
console.log(value.split(/\s+(?=\d:)/g))
```

Comment: Might want to split using this regex to prevent issues with the other colons: `/^\d*:/`

Comment: @JonathanGray yeah i  thanks for pointing out i completely overlooked that. fixed

Comment: @CodeManiac I can't split by space, since items can have space eg
0:'blah blah' 1:'blah blah'

Comment: @comalex3 i added it as your posted input in question. you can extend your question. will update my answer accordingly

Comment: @CodeManiac awesome, but for "meter_values": "\"0:'NY' 1:'LG' 2:'BG Los'\"", this won't work, since  2:'BG Los' has space in value

Comment: @comalex3 you can see the last console in second snipptet

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting using following regex

```js
let arr = "0:2017-12-31T19:00:00.000Z 1:2018-01-09T19:00:00.000Z 2:balh blah "

let out = arr.split(/\b\d{1}:/).slice(1)
console.log(out)
```